# Is there any command or function to monitor memory use in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

When many users use dolphindb at the same time, I want to know the memory use of every user? Is there any function or command?

Answer (score 0):

The following functions are related to monitoring of memory usage.

- `mem` http://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?mem.htm
- `getSessionMemoryStat`
- `getPerf`